How to join thread from another function
I have some code like:
import threading
import time

mode1=False
mode2=True

stop_thread=False

def function1():
     while True:
        print('function1')
        
        global stop_thread
        if stop_thread:
            break
def function2():
    while True:
        print('function2')
        
        global stop_thread
        if stop_thread:
            break

class MyClass():
    def run(self):
        if mode1:
            t = threading.Thread(target=function1, daemon=True)
            t.start()
        elif mode2:
            t = threading.Thread(target=function2, daemon=True)
            t.start()

    def stop(self):
        global stop_thread
        stop_thread=True
        # t.join() doesn't work here

        
v=MyClass()
v.run()
v.stop()

How can I make it possible to join() the thread from stop()?

Post code exactly as it is when if raises the error and post the full error traceback.

FYI: no need for global stop_thread it is only needed to reassign stop thread. So simply do while not stop_thread:.

The problem with your attempt to "make t global" is completely unrelated to the question - please see name 'times' is used prior to global declaration - But IT IS declared. I'm editing that out to focus the question properly.

You just need to save the reference to the thread as an attribute of the MyClass instance:
import threading
import time

mode1 = False

stop_thread = False

def function1():
     while True:
        print('function1')

        if stop_thread:
            break

def function2():
    while True:
        print('function2')

        if stop_thread:
            break

# t=None
class MyClass():
    def run(self):
        fn = function1 if mode1 else function2
        # Save reference to the thread as an attribute of this instance:
        self.t = threading.Thread(target=fn, daemon=True)
        self.t.start()

    def stop(self):
        global stop_thread #,t

        stop_thread = True
        self.t.join()
        print('thread has been joined')


v = MyClass()
v.run()
v.stop()

Prints:
function2
thread has been joined


There are superior patterns for this rather than using global sentinels. My preference is to use Events.
However, to answer the question as stated then:
import threading
import time

stop_thread = False
mode1 = False
mode2 = True


def function1():
    while not stop_thread:
        print("function 1")
        time.sleep(1)  # avoid thrashing


def function2():
    while not stop_thread:
        print("function 2")
        time.sleep(1)  # avoid thrashing


class MyClass:
    def run(self):
        if mode1:
            func = function1
        elif mode2:
            func = function2
        else:
            func = None
        if func is not None:
            self._thread = threading.Thread(target=func)
            self._thread.start()

    def stop(self):
        global stop_thread
        stop_thread = True
        self._thread.join()


v = MyClass()
v.run()
time.sleep(2)
v.stop()

